# Send pdf to database after window.print() in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I am dynamically generating an invoice. I make essential functions and design for printing the invoice. But I want to get the pdf file for sending it to database.
How can I achieve this with pure js.

Comment: What did you tried ? Where is your issue exactly ?

Comment: You would need to use something like html2pdf. But it's easier and more reliable to handle this on your backend, especially since otherwise anybody could tamper with the invoice (which is a legally relevant document of sorts).

Comment: after window.print() I wanna the file and send it to the backend server.